# CVS not working after switching windows user

Tags: eclipse, cvs

My cvs set up in eclipse was working fine but started giving problem when I switch  the windows user. I have windows 7 and earliar I used to log in with user X now I have switched to user Y. Now I am not able to sync with my cvs repository (my cvs user name and password have not changed) The error says -I/O has been interrupted.
Timeout while reading from input stream

is it happening because I have changed my windows log on?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The CVS client in Eclipse is not related/dependent to windows user. Possibly the user Y does not have read/write permission on the files created by user X ? The error given by CVS should have more details, maybe you can provide those as well.

Comment: Error details:-I/O has been interrupted.
Timeout while reading from input stream
  The most likely cause of the interrupt is either an intermittent network failure or a communications timeout.
  The CVS communications timeout can be adjusted in the Team/CVS preferences.
  Another possible cause is the improper configuration of the "ext" connection method.
  The "ext" connection method can be configured on the Team/CVS/EXT Connection Method preference page